# VSCode "Unable to open <HASH> Unable to read file"

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, containers

I'm using VSCode (1.52.1) for a while on my Fedora 33 machine.
I'm using Docker extension (v1.9.0) but for some reason, in the past few days when I'm trying to attach the VSCode to the Docker container, it failed to resolve the workspace folder.

I've tried to reinstall VSCode and the Docker extension but it did not help

I think [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/5361) is related

Screenshot:
[image]

As you can see, the files explorer does not show any files, instead, it shows a hash-like string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accourding to this vs-code [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/4304)

> You might have had that folder open before and it now no longer exists. Can you use File > Open Folder to open a different folder in the container?

All you need to do is go to
`File --> Open Folder` in the top menu
open the wanted folder and that it.

[image]

That worked for me